# Как указать стили для нескольких дочерних элементов?

Tags: html, css, scss

Мне надо указать определённые стили для **последних** 26 **дочерних** элементов, или хотя б фиксировано с 120 элемента до 146 элемента, и желательно чтоб не вручную прописывать для каждого элемента стили.

Использую **SCSS**(**SASS**) можно с помощью него.

Comment: https://denis-creative.com/iterating-over-nth-children-sass/ - вот тут есть, как с помощью sass указывать стили сразу для нескольких дочерних элементов

Answer (score 0):

В stylus попроще, но можно и в scss

```
// 36 loop iterations
@for $i from 120 through 146 { 
  div:nth-child(#{$i})::after {
    content: "$i == #{$i}";
    // multiply by 10 for larger hue increments
    background: hsl($i * 10 - 1200, 50%, 50%);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавь ко всем элементам класс, например так

```
<div class = "myDiv elem">
```

теперь у div-a два класса, все которые хочешь менять в стилях добавь класс(напр. elem) и меняй параметры класса elem в sass